# How to find a differential equation given its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was given the solution of a differential equation and I need to find its differential equation, specifically a second order differential equation with constant coefficients.

> $e^x + e^{-x} + e^{2x}$

Someone please help me with this. I am very confused since the solution has three terms. Doesn't the solution should contain only two terms since it is the solution of a second order differential equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An homogeneous second order differential equation $ay''+by'+cy=0$ has as solutions (if the associated polynomial does not have a double root) $c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x}$, where $r_1,r_2$ are the roots. If it is non-homogeneous, we must add the particular solution part.  We will concoct an equation based on this.

Let's say we want $e^{x}+e^{-x}$ to be the solution of the homogeneous part. Then the polynomial must be of the form $(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1,$ so we can let our differential equation be $y''-y=?$, where we will determine the $?$ now. Let $y=e^{2x}$, and let's see what the equation requires us to do now.

$$(e^{2x})''-(e^{2x})=4e^{2x}-e^{2x}=3e^{2x}.$$

Therefore, if we let the equation be
$$y''-y=3e^{2x},$$
everything falls into place. (Note that the equation is not unique)

Comment: Actually, it is y''-y = 3e^2x. I have tested using this: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/y''-y%3D3e%5E%7B2x%7D

Comment: @mathewconway You're right. Note that in the computation for some reason I put $y''-y'$, when it should be $y''-y$. Fixing.